# Database using Java

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am making an application similar to that of apps such as pay by phone and paymobile, which are apps used to pay for parking instead of using a parking meter and having to display a ticket in your vehicle.
I need to start with the back-end (the database) and was wondering if SQL would be appropriate for this app.

As SQLite is stored on the system (the Database) there will be data such parking details and  payment details.

Will I be able to send this data to say my laptop which will act as the server for the traffic wardens device to check number plates?
Or would I have to use a sql software that is not on the applications itself?

Any thoughts and suggestions would be much appreciated :D

Comment: For server-side, IMO the easiest way is to setup a MySQL server, and make some simple API to communicate between App and the DB server. Anyways, this question is way too broad, as it has too many potential answers.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is perfect for back end database needs. You can various flavors of SQL like Oracle or MySQL on the back end. As far as the application data being sent to the server (your backend laptop), that will be taken care by the application level programming. For android, there are various ways to send data, using the native class `AsyncTask` or using third party libraries like `Retrofit` and `Volley`. You need to take a decision depending on the architecture of your app.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

1. Create database on your server
2. Create Web API like .Net MVC on your server
3. Create connection between your Web API and your database
4. In your mobile app you can use webservice to get our put your data to database
5. You can encyrpt your data on your database to more safety

**do not use SQLite , because it is unsafe to keep your important data.**